# My strapi application is not starting due to error

Tags: mongodb, yarnpkg, strapi

I am facing this error when I am going to start my project with strapi as a backend.

[image]

and this is my package.json

[image]

I am using node 14.18.1 and yarn 1.22.19 and mongodb 4.2.
Help me solve this issue.

I want to start my profile that built with strapi 3

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`strapi-plugin-upload: "^0.0.0"`

looks like an error in this case